# font size and image size not respected when converting to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: html, css, image, pdf, itext

I've got some code that will convert HTML into PDF using iTextSharp, however, when I view the PDF, the font sizes and the size of images are different to what has been specified in the HTML.

My code is as below - any help would be appreciated:

```
Public Function RenderPdf() As MemoryStream

    Dim file As New MemoryStream()
    Dim document As New iTextSharp.text.Document(Me.PageSize)
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, file)
    document.Open()

    Dim tagProcessors As DefaultTagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory()
    tagProcessors.RemoveProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG) 'remove the default processor
    tagProcessors.AddProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG, New CustomImageTagProcessor()) 'use our new processor


    Using document
        'render each page that has been added
        For Each page As HtmlPdfPage In Me._Pages
            document.NewPage()

            'generate this page of text
            Dim output As New MemoryStream()
            Dim html As New StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8)

            Dim sr As New StringReader(page._Html.ToString())

            Dim cssFiles As New CssFilesImpl()
            cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCSS())
            Dim cssResolver As New StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles)
            Dim charset = Encoding.UTF8

            Dim hpc As New HtmlPipelineContext(New CssAppliersImpl(New XMLWorkerFontProvider()))
            hpc.SetAcceptUnknown(True).AutoBookmark(True).SetTagFactory(tagProcessors) 'inject the tagProcessors
            Dim htmlPipeline As New pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline(hpc, New PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer))
            Dim pipeline As New CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline)
            Dim worker As New XMLWorker(pipeline, True)
            Dim xmlParser As New iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser(True, worker, charset)
            xmlParser.Parse(sr)

        Next

        'return the rendered PDF
        Return file
    End Using

End Function


Public Class CustomImageTagProcessor
        Inherits iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Image
        Public Overrides Function [End](ctx As IWorkerContext, tag As Tag, currentContent As IList(Of IElement)) As IList(Of IElement)
            Dim attributes As IDictionary(Of String, String) = tag.Attributes
            Dim src As String
            If Not attributes.TryGetValue(HTML.Attribute.SRC, src) Then
                Return New List(Of IElement)(1)
            End If

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(src) Then
                Return New List(Of IElement)(1)
            End If

            If src.StartsWith("data:image/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                ' data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
                Dim base64Data = src.Substring(src.IndexOf(",") + 1)
                Dim imagedata = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data)
                Dim image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagedata)

                Dim list = New List(Of IElement)()
                Dim htmlPipelineContext = GetHtmlPipelineContext(ctx)
                list.Add(GetCssAppliers().Apply(New Chunk(DirectCast(GetCssAppliers().Apply(image, tag, htmlPipelineContext), iTextSharp.text.Image), 0, 0, True), tag, htmlPipelineContext))
                Return list
            Else
                Return MyBase.[End](ctx, tag, currentContent)
            End If
        End Function
    End Class
```

Example HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style id="mceDefaultStyles" type="text/css">
//<![CDATA[
.mce-content-body div.mce-resizehandle {position: absolute;border: 1px solid black;background: #FFF;width: 5px;height: 5px;z-index: 10000}.mce-content-body .mce-resizehandle:hover {background: #000}.mce-content-body img[data-mce-selected], hr[data-mce-selected] {outline: 1px solid black;resize: none}.mce-content-body .mce-clonedresizable {position: absolute;opacity: .5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);z-index: 10000}
img:-moz-broken {-moz-force-broken-image-icon:1;min-width:24px;min-height:24px}

//]]>//
</style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="http://localhost:60699/Scripts/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <style id="mceDefaultStyles" type="text/css">
//<![CDATA[
.mce-content-body div.mce-resizehandle {position: absolute;border: 1px solid black;background: #FFF;width: 5px;height: 5px;z-index: 10000}.mce-content-body .mce-resizehandle:hover {background: #000}.mce-content-body img[data-mce-selected], hr[data-mce-selected] {outline: 1px solid black;resize: none}.mce-content-body .mce-clonedresizable {position: absolute;outline: 1px dashed black;opacity: .5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);z-index: 10000}

//]]>//
</style>
    <link href="http://localhost:59372/Call_Scripter/Scripts/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-mce-href="http://localhost:59372/Call_Scripter/Scripts/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css" />
    <p>
        <br />
    </p>
    <table width="1000" align="center" class="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="width: 560px; padding-left: 80px;" data-mce-style="width: 560px; padding-left: 80px;">
                    <strong><span style="font-size: 18px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 18px;">Company Name</span><br />
                        ABN: 65 999 999 999<br />
                        PO Box 999<br />
                        Suburb, State, Postcode Australia<br />
                        Phone: 02 9999 9999 Fax: 02 9999 9999<br />
                        Email: anemailaddress@blahblah.com.au<br />
                        Web: www.blahblah.com.au </strong>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" rowspan="2">
                    &nbsp;<strong><span style="font-size: 18px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 18px;">Tax Invoice</span>
                    </strong>
                    <table class="" data-mce-selected="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="170" style="font-weight: bold;" data-mce-style="font-weight: bold;">
                                    Invoice Number:
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold;" data-mce-style="font-weight: bold;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Sales Order:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Invoice Date:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ABN:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    65 090 839 197
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Your Reference:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>Page 1 of 1</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 160px;" data-mce-style="padding-left: 160px;">
                    <strong></strong>Australia
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 25px;" colspan="2" data-mce-style="padding-right: 25px;">
                    <hr style="background: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 2px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                        border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;
                        display: block;" data-mce-style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 2px; background: transparent; background-color: #000; border-top: solid 1px #000; color: #000;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="top" style="width: 560px; height: 900px; padding-left: 80px;"
                    colspan="2" data-mce-style="width: 560px; padding-left: 80px; height: 900px;">
                    <table class="" style="width: 920px;" data-mce-selected="1" data-mce-style="width: 920px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>Product</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>Item Description</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <strong>Qty</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <strong>Unit Price (Ex GST)</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding-left: 10px;" data-mce-style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                    <strong>Unit</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <strong>Discount</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <strong>Net Amount</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <strong>GST</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <strong>Total</strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 220px;" data-mce-style="width: 220px;">
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td align="right">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="2" data-mce-style="font-weight: bold;">
                    <table align="right" class="" style="width: 450px;" data-mce-selected="1" data-mce-style="width: 450px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Total Page 1
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Grand Total AUD
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" style="text-align: left;" colspan="2" data-mce-style="text-align: left;">
                                    Balance Owing
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                    $0.00
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" style="text-align: left;" colspan="2" data-mce-style="text-align: left;">
                                    PAID IN FULL
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="width: 100px;" data-mce-style="width: 100px;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 25px;" colspan="2" data-mce-style="padding-right: 25px;">
                    <hr style="background: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 100%; height: 2px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                        border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;
                        display: block;" data-mce-style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 2px; background: transparent; background-color: #000; border-top: solid 1px #000; color: #000;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your HTML and CSS, specifically the font size part?

Comment: Sample HTML added as edit.

Comment: That's a pretty big snippet! ;) There's only two font size declarations in there since I can't see the CSS files. Are you sure that iTextSharp is seeing you CSS files? Put something really obvious but simple like `color: #ff000` to make sure its resolving correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching iTextSharp for HTML to PDF conversion, and instead, I went with this solution https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin - it means I can generate my PDF with 1 line of code and the PDF comes out perfectly !